# AWS CodeBuild - docker: not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I have the following buildspec.yml:

```html
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      -  curl -L -o sbt-0.13.6.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.6.deb && \
      -  dpkg -i sbt-0.13.6.deb && \
      -  rm sbt-0.13.6.deb && \
      -  apt-get update && \
      -  apt-get install sbt && \

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the pre_build phase...
      - docker login -u user -p pass

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - sbt test
      - echo test completed on `date`
      - sbt docker:publishLocal
      - docker tag image repo

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push repo

cache:
  paths:
    - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
    - $HOME/.sbt
```

and fails with

> /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: docker: not found

in the console. As far as I see in the examples provided in the doc, docker should be already given.

How can I avoid this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your CodeBuild project select the "privileged" flag to enable Docker in your build container. If you are using a CodeBuild managed image, then selecting this flag is all that's needed. If you are using a custom image then ensure the Docker is started as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html

Comment: This doooes not work for me, I get `nohup: failed to run command '/usr/local/bin/dockerd': No such file or directory`

Comment: @KakaRuto have you find the solution to the error you provided?

Comment: @MikitaHerasiutsin you need to install the docker on the custom image. The AWS doc page starts with a pre-installed docker. One way of doing it on ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175554 (will need to change the path to /usr/sbin/dockerd as well.

Comment: Yes @MikitaHerasiutsin, you would need to install docker on your image first as Vitoshka has said