# How to install Docker inside my ubuntu container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

I installed docker inside a container running on `ubuntu:18.04` to run my nodejs app, I need docker installed inside this container because i need to dockerize an other small app

Her is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install Nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl wget dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates software-properties-common gnupg-agent
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs

# Install Chromium
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst \
      --no-install-recommends
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Docker
RUN curl -fsSL https:/download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

When the container is up, i `docker exec -it app bash`.
If i do a `service docker start` then `ps ax`, got this

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  115 ?        Z      0:00 [dockerd] <defunct>
```

**What can i do to be able to use docker inside the container or is there a docker image not using apk but apt-get ?** Because when i need to use it, i got this error :

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install docker in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451859/how-to-install-docker-in-docker-container)

Comment: most probably is that you don't want to do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to access to other containers running on 127.0.0.1:port from myapp container

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First thing better to use one of the base images, either for [node-image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) and install docker and for [docker-image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) and installed node, instead of creating image from scratch. All you need

```
FROM  node:buster
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt install docker.io -y
RUN docker --version
ENTRYPOINT nohup dockerd >/dev/null 2>&1 & sleep 10 && node /app/app.js
```

second thing, The error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`, The reason is you are not starting the docker process in the Dockefile, and also running multiple processes in the container is not recommended, as if Docker process dies you will not know the status, you have to put one process in the background.

```
CMD nohup dockerd >/dev/null 2>&1 & sleep 10 && node /app/app.js
```

and run

```
docker run --privileged  -it -p 8000:8000  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock your_image
```

Comment: the problem with this method is that i cant curl the container i need with 127.0.0.1:port from the app container

Comment: where you need to curl? did you expose the desired port?

Comment: i exposed everything needed, i need to curl from myapp container. If i curl 127.0.0.1:5001 from localhost it works, if i curl from the container myapp i get an error

Comment: did you try with `curl localhost:5001` and can you show you are trying to do the call.

Comment: so, i need to use multiple proxy with my nodejs app to scrape a google page result.  Here are my proxy containers

`d314610709fb pry0cc/proxydock "supervisord -n" 22 hours ago Up 22 hours         127.0.0.1:5002->8080/tcp proxy_5002`
`1548f448a1b5 pry0cc/proxydock "supervisord -n" 22 hours ago        Up 22 hours 127.0.0.1:5001->8080/tcp proxy_5001`

Comment: So i need to use these containers by using there ip:port, so 127.0.0.1:5001 for example. The problem was that i cant do it like that i need to run these containers inside myapp container, i tried to use networks but the ip to call these proxy change each time i restart the proxy containers...

Comment: Your question and the comment are different, this answer is baed on your current question, you can open new question and as this answer solved your current problem